# Is it possible to lock records or attributes indefintely if a field is populated?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, c#, oracle-dbms, add-in

I am creating a c# ArcGIS addin where I have a feature class stored in Oracle, when a feature is created some of the fields within the table will be populated. If field X is populated, then certain fields will be locked, if field Y is populated then some other fields will be locked and if field Z is populated then the geometry will be locked.

Locked means no  edits can be done (geometry wise or the attributes) either  within the addin and outside in ArcGIS or even in Oracle.

Is this something that can be done? If so, does anyone have any pointers to get me started?

EDIT - There may be a scenario where the feature class is joined to table and that table will have a field that locks the geometry. How would it be possible to lock the spatial table?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a field to be read only in ArcMap. When in table view mode click on a header and look at it's properties.  A quick search of the ArcObjects API and it's the interface *IFieldInfo3* that can set this property. You can get a handle on this via the *ILayerFields* interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you want these restrictions to apply at the database level then that would likely be where you would have to implement them, ArcGIS or ArcSDE could not prevent a user with SQL access from making updates.

For an enterprise solution Oracle offer [Virtual Private Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/vpd.htm) that adds row and column granularity to database permissions, however this is likely out of reach for your project.

An alternative could be to have `before update` and `on insert` triggers on your table that prevent updates being applied depending on your rules.

These would be enforced whether the updates were made from Oracle or your addin, though you have to be careful with this type of trigger though to ensure the logic is sound as otherwise the updates could be lost. e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_PREVENT_UPDATES
BEFORE UPDATE
ON MY_TABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

if :old.x is not null
then 
-- Prevent fields being updated if x is set
-- You could either ignore the new values or throw an error
:new.col1 := :old.col1;
:new.col2 := :old.col2; -- This will silently drop the users changes.
end if;

end;
```

If you need help with setting up a database trigger then [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) would be the best community to help you.

Comment: thanks, i may have omitted some details (i have edited the question). The feature class may be joined to a table, and that table might have a field that locks the geometry record. How would the triggers know what geometry row, and what geometry table needs to be locked?

Comment: If the joined table is also in Oracle then you could also create a trigger on the second table, which checks table1 if necessary to determine whether to apply the updates.  This is getting towards quite a complicated structure though with some risks - for example if table 1 is updated while the trigger on table2 is thinking about the update etc..